# Debug scheme won't build - Apple Mach-O Linker Error. Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, linker, cocoapods

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get this error way too often and it's driving me (and the team nuts). The project was building just fine last week and I did nothing to the project in the mean time, just opened it yesterday and now I'm getting this error when building using the Debug scheme only; Adhoc builds fine. I'm running the latest Yosemite, Xcode 6.1 (but this has plagued me for many months anyway). My instructions to resolve it work occasionally, like black magic:

Clean

Restart Xcode

Delete derived data (check preferences/locations)

Pod update

Open project using the Workspace file

Delete the workspace file and run pod install

But unfortunately this time it's just not working! I've done this process over and over. I'm so frustrated with this PoS Xcode. Next step would be to re-download the project from Git, but there must be a better way! I have gone through a number of other stack overflow posts but found nothing to help (nor anything very recent). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The same error drove me nuts for two days. I fixed through the following :

**Project > Targets > Build Settings > Packaging > Product Name** - Check if the product name has changed.

Also try setting the **Build Active Architecture to NO** in your project..

**Project/Pods > Build Settings > Architectures > Build Active Architecture Only**

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestions. I ended up having to re-download the entire project, so it's working now. I will definitely test this next time (it's bound to happen again) and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `build` folder of your project and rebuild it again. Always works for me!